# multiplying elements of array is giving infinity for large number of inputs in javascript while performing this problem in hackerearth

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript i try to solve this problem from hackerearth its giving infinity while try to multiply very large set of numbers its just a simple array multiplication its working fine with small inputs but for large inputs its giving infinity ,Thanks in advance for the people who are going to help me
this is the question link https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/find-product/

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";


process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;     
    // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});

function main(input) {
    let arr = input.split('\n');
    let array = parseInt(arr[1].split(" "))
    let result = 1;

    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        result = result*array[i]
    }
    console.log(result)
    // Writing output to STDOUT
}
```

```
this is the input 
1000
246 667 10 462 11 119 977 817 882 599 119 908 866 109 870 18 910 169 604 766 955 393 522 434 39 379 510 404 649 615 699 574 954 898 588 574 767 459 127 398 912 25 82 602 335 711 86 162 332 328 644 999 296 882 200 844 297 264 650 221 246 761 46 756 143 593 510 900 634 115 618 180 777 420 614 41 863 946 961 999 667 470 224 107 211 80 866 759 791 903 1000 413 910 292 716 432 706 161 461 494 554 17 904 231 101 977 64 206 599 454 573 432 134 356 447 141 50 228 807 806 847 835 104 715 95 163 750 118 639 630 374 609 213 950 68 449 987 129 168 273 842 306 452 475 572 334 284 91 819 154 827 263 455 489 801 831 28 99 300 923 166 28 370 802 948 987 304 825 645 250 317 875 232 595 788 199 625 405 865 513 627 867 98 639 735 514 460 681 727 674 767 987 796 134 961 937 999 267 272 597 680 20 294 170 907 539 444 583 258 866 457 753 384 473 253 291 722 478 264 471 752 436 279 132 143 491 139 20 146 528 182 411 591 226 546 651 909 807 770 903 639 801 892 272 125 190 249 497 682 143 847 478 243 362 661 749 140 811 23 666 428 265 733 507 268 896 486 126 928 352 84 412 533 614 452 728 396 413 703 580 983 83 502 963 434 749 285 680 407 129 29 463 265 919 533 980 764 744 493 644 720 100 646 1 934 496 752 464 153 410 648 212 987 228 165 465 920 621 318 526 767 171 576 87 966 344 973 427 216 534 90 81 493 316 884 210 577 630 548 632 166 748 420 124 134 537 63 380 190 34 641 133 574 890 790 598 62 771 736 539 150 881 54 354 850 869 416 105 280 442 52 519 786 511 998 269 194 754 745 378 670 832 853 752 806 855 199 181 194 370 86 684 763 914 439 158 440 412 411 989 299 14 200 461 545 421 401 128 452 519 8 478 570 693 892 631 940 675 292 820 737 629 89 59 288 859 831 605 40 876 900 268 906 592 248 424 133 45 695 761 993 727 682 417 412 757 155 434 551 95 580 846 386 499 566 623 432 378 79 593 671 297 624 647 846 3 719 221 122 396 571 729 25 760 967 32 522 459 107 293 112 945 559 531 979 321 698 124 384 176 726 14 467 653 425 730 1 424 803 901 446 465 411 761 742 857 747 273 28 590 257 169 276 791 126 888 124 79 131 665 224 43 1 388 543 672 881 277 273 596 367 514 2 26 380 796 239 164 424 199 716 104 283 872 921 943 624 628 917 556 29 33 538 89 951 853 661 292 605 3 314 908 120 985 735 150 273 498 698 900 960 466 479 349 548 736 986 614 496 934 473 75 23 594 557 113 524 526 277 454 796 638 417 425 13 750 900 862 132 190 276 317 224 624 574 636 199 17 43 679 312 520 207 370 750 767 373 491 402 327 828 181 732 510 882 792 93 296 326 802 218 195 591 406 46 466 954 804 111 81 598 791 276 941 81 510 276 513 128 268 654 280 822 615 215 197 458 23 540 352 368 749 707 654 433 391 483 115 204 547 924 508 586 495 602 400 977 795 882 767 432 489 734 448 373 22 987 834 43 602 759 544 743 39 174 760 347 544 863 707 305 357 246 866 992 169 549 277 962 879 912 520 992 306 286 501 590 192 15 73 408 788 694 666 223 860 580 1 650 494 485 302 519 681 681 719 561 497 813 116 520 810 710 345 5 88 465 408 18 381 718 72 655 36 344 378 7 82 971 642 918 714 525 225 493 254 525 454 899 802 482 984 188 586 162 928 894 858 459 893 172 843 753 46 834 679 552 317 508 351 628 691 641 66 877 255 149 449 848 504 120 911 761 824 207 695 245 360 805 441 692 102 137 817 988 29 2 210 220 597 828 775 34 465 397 806 453 992 366 501 177 649 689 254 109 220 665 530 98 929 180 675 895 157 172 376 721 796 793 328 574 827 85 770 431 928 789 658 985 44 489 252 36 237 279 633 837 98 807 292 842 473 126 888 196 182 454 266 211 450 434 23 882 443 536 862 386 472 872 885 174 247 290 606 74 461 89 686 27 713 867 426 320 745 404 549 723 214 792 114 761 813 408 642 829 893 515 880 95 487 455 963 504 6 812 277 814 922 67 490 578 784 449 942 41 934 495 191 146 744 221 338 391 14 696 400 617 507 588 838 746 71 959 465 122 12 829 871 977 220 276 22 835 854 882 271 79 742 231 21 338 627 960 567 972 177 13 84 156 437 350 710 524 283 505 61 207 660 662 945 293 598 860 617 719 502 680 794 123 520
```

Comment: JavaScript has a biggest and smallest possible number. If you exceed them you get `Inifnity` and `-Inifinity` respectively.

Comment: @nickzoum could help me with the maximum number of digit javascript can process like the expected output for the above problem is this 328683326  can't js give these number of digits as output instead giving infinity ?

Comment: You are missing the main point of this exercise, meaning you lack the required knowledge in the respective fields to solve it - the problem is not meant for you. If you want to solve it anyways, start reading about modular arithmetic, e.g. in a book, or an online course. The solution should become apparent (or likely will even be an exercise in the course/book itself), when the mathematical foundation has been tought.

Comment: @Hashimaslam All of these numbers are bigger than `100`, and there are `1000` of them. So the result is going to be bigger than `1E2000`. Most JavaScript engines can't deal with numbers that are bigger than `1E308`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte The problem is that JavaScript can't calculate numbers that are bigger than `1E309`.

Comment: @nickzoum the problem's goal is that you cannot simply multiply them all up. If you read the link, the crucial part is "modulo 10^9 + 7". It's a stereotypical problem from a modular arithmetics course.

Comment: @ASDFGerte There was no mention in the question and I didn't see that in the link. With the module then the problem is indeed feasible.

Comment: I think I've to learn a lot more in javascript honestly I didn't understand what is 1E308 and modulo 10^9+7 anyways thank you so much for the solution guys

Comment: Those aren't JavaScript notations, those are simple Math/Physics notations. `1E308` means `10^308`  and `modulo 10^9+7` means `x % (10^9+7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most JavaScript engines you cannot use numbers exceeding `1E309`. The product of all those numbers is much larger than that and is therefore interpreted as `Infinity`.

You did however fail to mention that question description states you should store the module of the product and not the product itself which guarantees the result will be smaller than `1E9 + 7`.

```js
function main(input) {
  var module = Math.pow(10, 9) + 7;
  console.log(input.split(" ").reduce((res, item) => (res * +item) % module, 1));
}

var input = `246 667 10 462 11 119 977 817 882 599 119 908 866 109 870 18 910 169 604 766 955 393 522 434 39 379 510 404 649 615 699 574 954 898 588 574 767 459 127 398 912 25 82 602 335 711 86 162 332 328 644 999 296 882 200 844 297 264 650 221 246 761 46 756 143 593 510 900 634 115 618 180 777 420 614 41 863 946 961 999 667 470 224 107 211 80 866 759 791 903 1000 413 910 292 716 432 706 161 461 494 554 17 904 231 101 977 64 206 599 454 573 432 134 356 447 141 50 228 807 806 847 835 104 715 95 163 750 118 639 630 374 609 213 950 68 449 987 129 168 273 842 306 452 475 572 334 284 91 819 154 827 263 455 489 801 831 28 99 300 923 166 28 370 802 948 987 304 825 645 250 317 875 232 595 788 199 625 405 865 513 627 867 98 639 735 514 460 681 727 674 767 987 796 134 961 937 999 267 272 597 680 20 294 170 907 539 444 583 258 866 457 753 384 473 253 291 722 478 264 471 752 436 279 132 143 491 139 20 146 528 182 411 591 226 546 651 909 807 770 903 639 801 892 272 125 190 249 497 682 143 847 478 243 362 661 749 140 811 23 666 428 265 733 507 268 896 486 126 928 352 84 412 533 614 452 728 396 413 703 580 983 83 502 963 434 749 285 680 407 129 29 463 265 919 533 980 764 744 493 644 720 100 646 1 934 496 752 464 153 410 648 212 987 228 165 465 920 621 318 526 767 171 576 87 966 344 973 427 216 534 90 81 493 316 884 210 577 630 548 632 166 748 420 124 134 537 63 380 190 34 641 133 574 890 790 598 62 771 736 539 150 881 54 354 850 869 416 105 280 442 52 519 786 511 998 269 194 754 745 378 670 832 853 752 806 855 199 181 194 370 86 684 763 914 439 158 440 412 411 989 299 14 200 461 545 421 401 128 452 519 8 478 570 693 892 631 940 675 292 820 737 629 89 59 288 859 831 605 40 876 900 268 906 592 248 424 133 45 695 761 993 727 682 417 412 757 155 434 551 95 580 846 386 499 566 623 432 378 79 593 671 297 624 647 846 3 719 221 122 396 571 729 25 760 967 32 522 459 107 293 112 945 559 531 979 321 698 124 384 176 726 14 467 653 425 730 1 424 803 901 446 465 411 761 742 857 747 273 28 590 257 169 276 791 126 888 124 79 131 665 224 43 1 388 543 672 881 277 273 596 367 514 2 26 380 796 239 164 424 199 716 104 283 872 921 943 624 628 917 556 29 33 538 89 951 853 661 292 605 3 314 908 120 985 735 150 273 498 698 900 960 466 479 349 548 736 986 614 496 934 473 75 23 594 557 113 524 526 277 454 796 638 417 425 13 750 900 862 132 190 276 317 224 624 574 636 199 17 43 679 312 520 207 370 750 767 373 491 402 327 828 181 732 510 882 792 93 296 326 802 218 195 591 406 46 466 954 804 111 81 598 791 276 941 81 510 276 513 128 268 654 280 822 615 215 197 458 23 540 352 368 749 707 654 433 391 483 115 204 547 924 508 586 495 602 400 977 795 882 767 432 489 734 448 373 22 987 834 43 602 759 544 743 39 174 760 347 544 863 707 305 357 246 866 992 169 549 277 962 879 912 520 992 306 286 501 590 192 15 73 408 788 694 666 223 860 580 1 650 494 485 302 519 681 681 719 561 497 813 116 520 810 710 345 5 88 465 408 18 381 718 72 655 36 344 378 7 82 971 642 918 714 525 225 493 254 525 454 899 802 482 984 188 586 162 928 894 858 459 893 172 843 753 46 834 679 552 317 508 351 628 691 641 66 877 255 149 449 848 504 120 911 761 824 207 695 245 360 805 441 692 102 137 817 988 29 2 210 220 597 828 775 34 465 397 806 453 992 366 501 177 649 689 254 109 220 665 530 98 929 180 675 895 157 172 376 721 796 793 328 574 827 85 770 431 928 789 658 985 44 489 252 36 237 279 633 837 98 807 292 842 473 126 888 196 182 454 266 211 450 434 23 882 443 536 862 386 472 872 885 174 247 290 606 74 461 89 686 27 713 867 426 320 745 404 549 723 214 792 114 761 813 408 642 829 893 515 880 95 487 455 963 504 6 812 277 814 922 67 490 578 784 449 942 41 934 495 191 146 744 221 338 391 14 696 400 617 507 588 838 746 71 959 465 122 12 829 871 977 220 276 22 835 854 882 271 79 742 231 21 338 627 960 567 972 177 13 84 156 437 350 710 524 283 505 61 207 660 662 945 293 598 860 617 719 502 680 794 123 520`;

main(input);
```